# How can I see more details of errors on rails heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am running my rails app on heroku, I am getting a 500 error but there is no details on what exactly the error is all about.

```
 at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=406f3afd-cbbf-4c92-969a-4445d486b451 fwd="213.16.235.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
```

How can I get a more detailed error message?
I have tried longentries with no luck, I am getting the some entry on longentries.

Comment: I normally install some kind of exception reporting tool (sentry, honeybadger or similar).

Comment: Sentry is probably the easiest as you just have to add the gem to your production group and install the add on from heroku dashboard.